# Prevent axes from being in scientific notation (powers of 10) using matplotlib in Python on semilogy plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, scientific-notation

I've read here ([How to prevent numbers being changed to exponential form in Python matplotlib figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711655/how-to-prevent-numbers-being-changed-to-exponential-form-in-python-matplotlib-fi)) and here ([Matplotlib: disable powers of ten in log plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637689/matplotlib-disable-powers-of-ten-in-log-plot)) and tried their solutions to no avail.

**How can I convert my y-axis to display normal decimal numbers instead of scientific notation?** Note this is Python 3.5.2.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
#Imports:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

possible_chars = 94
max_length = 8
pw_possibilities = [] 
for num_chars in range(1, max_length+1):
    pw_possibilities.append(possible_chars**num_chars)

x = range(1, max_length+1)
y = pw_possibilities 

#plot 
plt.figure()
plt.semilogy(x, y, 'o-')
plt.xlabel("num chars in password")
plt.ylabel("number of password possibilities")
plt.title("password (PW) possibilities verses # chars in PW")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How do you want to display `10^15`?  As `1000000000000000` ?!  The other answer applies to the default formatter, when you switch to log scale a `LogFormatter` is used which has a different set of rules.  You can switch back to `ScalarFormatter` and disable the offset

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
plt.ion()

possible_chars = 94
max_length = 8
pw_possibilities = [] 
for num_chars in range(1, max_length+1):
    pw_possibilities.append(possible_chars**num_chars)

x = range(1, max_length+1)
y = pw_possibilities 

#plot 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.semilogy(x, y, 'o-')
ax.set_xlabel("num chars in password")
ax.set_ylabel("number of password possibilities")
ax.set_title("password (PW) possibilities verses # chars in PW")
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_scientific(False)
ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example output]

See http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html for all of the available `Formatter` classes.

(this image is generated off of the 2.x branch, but should work on all recent version of mpl)

Comment: Looks great! I'm showing this to a middle-schooler, so yes, although 10^15 is unreadable as 1000000000000000, it has more of an impact to them with all of the zeros. Is it possible to force a format that puts commas  every 3 zeros?

Comment: See edit, you probably want to use http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.StrMethodFormatter or http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter

Comment: It still works! I just used this again! The secret is to put the 3 `ax.yaxis.` formatting lines _after_ I set up the rest of the plot and the log-y axes! Otherwise, those changes apparently get internally overwritten when you set the semilogy and other plot parameters.