# Matplotlib disable exponent notation in semilogy plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, scientific-notation

Let's say I have the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.semilogy([0,1],[20,90])
plt.show()
```

which creates the following figure:

[image]

I would like to disable the scientific notation on the y-axis (so I would like to have 20, 30, 40, 60, instead of 2x10^1, etc.)

I already had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336020/prevent-axes-from-being-in-scientific-notation-powers-of-10-using-matplotlib-i) thread, and I tried adding

```
import matplotlib.ticker
plt.gca().get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
plt.gca().get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_scientific(False)
plt.gca().get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
```

but it does not affect the resulting figure. I am using python 3.5.3, and matplotlib 2.1.0. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ticks on the y axis are within less than a decade, they are minor ticks, not major ticks. Hence you need to set the **minor formatter** to a `ScalarFormatter`.

```
plt.gca().yaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
```

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker

plt.figure()
plt.semilogy([0,1],[20,90])
plt.gca().yaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Aaaaah, that's what I was missing. Thanks a lot! :)